# How to write a RethinkDB merge query which handles null results

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb

How can I write a RethinkDB query for a document which returns a merged version of the document if it is found, and `null` otherwise?

The following, naive, query (written in JavaScript) causes an exception to be thrown from `.merge` in case `.get` returns `null` (i.e. the user isn't found):

```
r.table('users')
  .get(username)
  .merge((user) => {
    return {
      'projects': r.table('projects').getAll(username, {index: 'owner',})
        .coerceTo('array'),
    }
  })
  .run(conn)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing a merge query, while handling the case where a document is not found, can be accomplished through the use of [`do`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/do/) and [`branch`](https://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/branch/), so that `merge` only gets invoked on non-null results:

```
r.table('users')
  .get(username)
  .do((user) => {
    // Only perform a merge if user isn't null
    return r.branch(
      user.eq(null),
      null,
      user.merge({
        'projects': r.table('projects').getAll(username, {index: 'owner',})
          .coerceTo('array'),
      })
    )
  })
  .run(conn)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post the answer to your own question! Very helpful :-)

Comment: @David Thanks for the feedback, glad it helped someone :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add `.default(null)` after the merge query to handle non-existence errors (although this will also handle any other non-existence errors inside the merge query).

Comment: Can you exemplify in code what you mean, so I can test?

Comment: I tested adding `.default(null)` after the `merge` part of the query. It actually works, but it's not clear to me at all how :/ As such, I prefer the explicitness of `do`/`branch`.